# SQL Server won't print out my variable when I am using EXEC sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Why is no result being shown? I think everything is fine, it should work, but when I print the output variable it prints nothing

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Qry = 'select [forid1].[2/17/2017] from [forid1]'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Qry, N'@Result NVARCHAR(20) OUTPUT', @Result  OUTPUT;

PRINT ' value is : ' + @Result  ;
```

Comment: if `@Result` is null then it wont print

Comment: no its not null its value is 'p' and EXECUTE print it with column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the @Result variable in your dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- assign the @Result inside the dynamic SQL
SET @Qry='select @Result=[forid1].[2/17/2017] from [forid1]'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql @Qry, N'@Result NVARCHAR(20) OUTPUT', @Result  OUTPUT;
print ' value is : ' + @Result  ;
```

Comment: would you mean by set @Result

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Sorry

Comment: i mean how to assign the output variable

Comment: This is the crucial part: `select @Result=[forid1].[2/17/2017]`